# Magento 1.9 - PayPal Express mixes Magento's country with PayPal's address

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-express, country-regions

I am in the process of updating a `Magento 1.8 to 1.9.2.4`.  I am doing it on a local development environment.  I have a custom theme and a fair number of plugins.

**My theme**: http://themeforest.net/item/athlete-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/7190141

**Plugins** (the ones I figure are potentially problematic):

```
Ebizmarts_AbandonedCart
Idev_OneStepCheckout
Innoext Zone Manager
MageCoders_PaypalMulticurrency
MageWorx_OrdersEdit
```

**Expected results:**

When I checkout with PayPal Express, my PayPal address should be used in the review page.  If the country chosen in PayPal is not available, there should be a warning on the review page, or a method to edit the country.

**Actual results:**

When I checkout with PayPal Express and choose a country in PayPal that is not available to my site, Magento defaults to `United States, California, 90034`.  I end up with the street address from PayPal, and the default country OR the `country + state/province + zip/post code` that I chose in the **Estimate shipping and tax** block on the Cart page.

---

If I proceed to checkout on Magento and fill out my address there, PayPal forces that address and I cannot modify it in PayPal, nor in the review page.  So PayPal standard works fine, just not the Express button found in the `/checkout/cart/` page.

This wasn't a problem before the update because the review page allowed the customer to change his address.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?  Is there patch?

I've done some debugging and found the `returnFromPaypal()` function in `/app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php` where PayPal's address and Magento's address are merged.

but I don't want to modify duplicate this file into `/app/code/local/` if someone else has already found a solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this problem?

Comment: No, I ended up staying on 1.8.  You're experiencing this problem, too?

Comment: Yeah, onestepcheck from IDev overwrites the country with the default country. If I don't set a default country, it doesn't automatically select the shipping method and express fails unless I add in the review page for them to select the free shipping method.

Comment: OK.  That seems to confirm that it is a problem with IDev OneStepCheckout, so it might be worth contacting them.  I think I deleted my dev, so I'd have to re-install.  If you decide to contact them, please post the results back here!  :)  I'll do the same once I have time, but it might not be for a few months or more.

Comment: I have sent them two emails so far. Unfortunately they don't seem to want to respond at all! Will post results if I get anything good though, absolutely!